# How to clean up bootloaders & UEFI entries from other installs?

Tags: boot, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I got a new Windows laptop, and I wanted to dual boot with Linux. I installed Fedora, before changing my mind and going back to Mint. I'd like to keep Win 8.1 and Mint.

However, now my UEFI boot menu contains five entries:
[image]

The first two take me to Grub, which I guess is leftover from my Fedora install. The next two both take me to Linux Mint, and the last takes me to Win 8.1.

I'd like to remove both Fedora entries and one Linux Mint entry. The "Setup" interface makes it pretty simple to understand how, but:

1. I'd like to make sure deleting those entries isn't something stupid
2. I don't know how to handle those remnants of Grub that are left from the Fedora install. Should I delete them? Ignore them?

If I do delete the Grub remnants, I'm not sure how to do so, or even which partition it's on. Here's a look at my [partition table in Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1Mu0.png) and my [partition table in Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BWe2.png). Last but not least, here's what EasyBCD shows:

```
There are a total of 5 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 8.1
Timeout: 30 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Fedora
BCD ID: {51954931-ff5c-11e4-8caa-f68841e7e615}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \EFI\FEDORA\SHIM.EFI

Entry #2
Name: ubuntu
BCD ID: {51954933-ff5c-11e4-8caa-f68841e7e615}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI

Entry #3
Name: UEFI OS
BCD ID: {51954932-ff5c-11e4-8caa-f68841e7e615}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI

Entry #4
Name: ubuntu
BCD ID: {51954934-ff5c-11e4-8caa-f68841e7e615}
Device: \Device\HarddiskVolume1
Bootloader Path: \EFI\UBUNTU\GRUBX64.EFI

Entry #5
Name: Windows 8.1
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.efi
```

How should I handle these extra boot options without bricking my laptop?

Comment: In the same boat as OP, had Linux Mint+Win10 and installed Fedora over Linux Mint, so I now have Fedora+Win10.  Boot menu shows: OS Manager (Windows), ubuntu (grub), Fedora (x2, twice).  Running "efibootmgr -v" shows: \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi, \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi, \EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi, and \EFI\fedora\shim.efi

Answer (score 13):

In Linux use the command efibootmgr

```
efibootmgr -v
```

lists entries.

```
efibootmgr -b 0002 -B
```

would remove entry number 2 from the menu.

In case you wanted to regenerate these values in case they are deleted:
First mount your ESP. Usually to /boot/efi but /mnt is fine too. Then

```
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=[ESP mount] --bootloader-id=[name]
```

(this does not reconfigure GRUB)

If you need to reenter the entry for Fedora or Ubuntu using Shim instead of GRUB

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -L Fedora -d /dev/sdX -p Y -l \\EFI\\fedora\\shim.efi
```

`X` is the device and `Y` is the partition number of the EFI system partition (ESP).

Also, note that `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI` will be loaded when you select the hard disk from UEFI instead of one of the NVRAM entries.

Comment: Make sure you check the `BootCurrent` option. This is the boot entry that is used to start the system.  Ref: https://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

Answer (score 0):

This does not edit the partition, just the boot file. The various boots are still there. There comes a time when you either increase the size of the EFI partition or just nuke and pave.

I'm a multibooter, one of my machines currently has 8 distros on it and has had as many as 12. I change them from time to time. If I load rEFInd, I get something like 20 boot entries, usually with very little or nothing to differentiate several of them from several others. I want to be able to remove the boot files entirely for, say, OpenMandriva or Manjaro, not just remove the entry from the menu.

Comment: You have posted as answer something that looks like a new question. Have you fixed this? If yes, post a question and an answer, or a new answer here (editing the above). - As for the problem of leftovers on the EFI partition [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/931016/1039759) mentions the possibility of manually removing them.